# Text in markers from KML doesn't show in OL3

Tags: openlayers-3

I am importing KML files to overlay on a map.

OL3 does a great job with the geometry, but seems to ignore the text labels that should show up with them.

This snippet will put up a pin, but will not show the text in the `<name>` element as it did in Google Earth and Maps

```
<Placemark>
    <name>Text I want to show</name>
    <Point>
        <coordinates>-81.11918192120308,32.27372446636573,0</coordinates>
    </Point>
</Placemark>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing in the specification of KML that states that the `<name>` tag of a `<Placemark>` should be rendered along with a pushpin or icon -- Google just chose to implement it that way.

If you look at the OpenLayers [Swiss hotels KML](http://openlayers.org/en/v3.0.0/examples/kml.html?q=kml) example, you will probably agree that automatically showing the text labels would make the screen too busy. However, it is fairly straightforward to add labels on mouseover, using the `map.forEachFeatureAtPixel` function, as is done in this [kml earthquake](http://openlayers.org/en/v3.0.0/examples/kml-earthquakes.html?q=kml) exmaple, which pushes the name attribute of the KML tag into an info div, as you can see in this code snippet:

```
var feature = map.forEachFeatureAtPixel(pixel, function(feature, layer) {
   return feature;
});
if (feature) {
  info.tooltip('hide')
    .attr('data-original-title', feature.get('name'))
    .tooltip('fixTitle')
    .tooltip('show');
} else {
  info.tooltip('hide');
}
```

So, the `<name>` tag of `<Placemark>` is parsed, but the display is left up to you in OpenLayers, by design, not by defect.